# Problems removing a value from a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary in which each key has a certain amount of images saved.
Like this:

```
key 1: [image1, image2, image3, image4]
```

After calculating the SSIM between each image of the key and the
last image of the key:
For example:

```
s1 = ssim(image4, image1)
```

If the value of `s` is bigger than a threshold, the image is kept in the dictionary.

```
key 1: [image1, image2, image3, image4]
```

If the value of `s` is less than a threshold, the image is deleted in the dictionary.
Then:

```
key 1: [image2, image3, image4]
```

But in doing this I get the error:

```
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

**CODE**

```py
for img in range(len(img_dict1[key])):
    similarity=ssim(img_dict1[key][-1],img_dict1[key][img])
    if similarity > 0.85:
        continue
    else:
        img_dict1[key] = list(img_dict1[key]).pop(img)
```

Comment: So each key is a dictionary as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about modifying the thing you are iterating over. To avoid that in this case you could use something called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
img_dict1[key] = [img_dict1[key][i] for i in range(len(img_dict1[key]))
                    if ssim(img_dict1[key][-1], img_dict1[key][i]) > 0.85]
```

This replaces the list with a new version that only has the elements in it you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```py
for img in range(len(img_dict1[key])):
    similarity=ssim(img_dict1[key][-1],img_dict1[key][img])
    if similarity > 0.85:
        continue
    else:
        img_dict1[key].pop(img)
```

**Explanation:**  `pop` automatically removes the element from the list/dictionary and modifies the list/dictionary on call. You only assign pop to a value if you want to use that value later. In your case, you don't need to assign it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifing the `img_dict1[key]` list while you iterate its elements. So at the end of loop the list could be shorter than at begining. `len(img_dict1[key])` is evaluated once, at the begining.

More pythonic is to build new list:

```py
img_dict1[key] = [x for x in img_dict[key]
                  if ssim(img_dict1[key][-1], x) > 0.85]
```